# In mongodb, need quotes around keys for CRUD operations, example: "_id" vs _id?

Tags: mongodb

I'm reading over the MongoDB manual. Some examples, have quotes around the key values, e.g: `db.test.find({"_id" : 5})` and others don't, e.g: `db.test.find({_id : 5})`

Both quoted and un-quoted versions work. But I'm wondering if there are some nuanced difference here I don't know about or is one a preferred best practice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In JavaScript (the language of the MongoDB shell) those are treated exactly the same.  The quotes *are* needed, however, when a key contains a period like when you're using dot notation to match against an embedded field as in:

```js
db.test.find({"name.last": "Jones"})
```

My preference is to not use the quotes unless they're needed.

Comment: Good to note that this is because you are actually inputting an object, not a JSON string as some think. You are essentially calling the `find()` function with an object as the first param.

Comment: Why are the quotes needed in that case? (when using dot notation)

Comment: @user129393192 That's a JavaScript requirement. It will flag is as an invalid syntax without quotes.

Comment: Do you know if there is any reason behind the requirement?